# Kendo custom filter not refreshing on kendo grid data change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filter, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have implemented the kendo grid custom menu filter as given in the below example. It works fine, but when there is another distinct value that gets added to the grid the filter does not get updated even post refresh of the kendo grid. Please let me know as to how to proceed with this.

https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/filter-menu-customization

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your  implementation?

Comment: The example is read only Show your update code.

Comment: Sometimes you need to refresh with (Ctrl + F5) then effects take place properly.